# Playing audios using MediaPlayer class(track gets played only for first time)

Tags: android, audio, android-mediaplayer

Below is the code for the listview adapter which displays list of tracks.Each list item has play and stop icons to play and stop track.The issue I am having is that track gets played only for first time when i  click on play button.After that if i stop it by clicking on stop button and the try to play any track it doesn't get played.Through toast message i found out that    holder.img1.setOnClickListener() method does get called but onPrepared() method doesn't get called on clicking on play button for second time or after that.However onPrepared() method does get called for first time thats why track gets played for the first time..

If i put   `mMediaPlayer=new MediaPlayer();`inside onClick() method of        `holder.img1.setOnClickListener`above issue does get resolved but then clicking on multiple play buttons will start playing multiple tracks at same time which i don't want..
Here is the code .. `holder.img1` is for play icon and `holder.img2` is for stop icon

SoundCloudAdapter

```
public class SoundCloudAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<SoundCloud> soundcloudList;

    public SoundCloudAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<SoundCloud> soundcloudList)
    {
        this.context=context;
        this.soundcloudList = soundcloudList;
        mMediaPlayer=new MediaPlayer();
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return soundcloudList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position)
    {
        return soundcloudList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        final ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null){
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.soundcloud_item, null);
            holder.textview = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            holder.textview2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.id);
            holder.textview3 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.download);
            // holder.btn = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button);
            holder.img1 = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.play2);
            holder.img2 = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.pause);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }else{
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.textview.setText(soundcloudList.get(position).getTitle());
        holder.textview2.setText(soundcloudList.get(position).getId());
        holder.textview3.setText("Play Count : "+soundcloudList.get(position).getDownload());
        if(soundcloudList.get(position).getPlaying())
        {

            holder.img1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.img2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        else
        {

            holder.img1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.img2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        holder.img1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(final View v)
            {

                Toast.makeText(context,"img1",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                soundcloudList.get(position).setPlaying(true);
                try
                {
                    holder.img1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    holder.img2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    if(mMediaPlayer.isPlaying())
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(context,"isplaying",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        mMediaPlayer.pause();
                    }

                    mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                    mMediaPlayer.setDataSource("http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/" + soundcloudList.get(position).getId() + "/stream?client_id=xyz");
                    mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
                    mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp)
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(context,"prepatre",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            mp.start();

                        }
                    });
                    mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(
                            new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener()
                            {
                                @Override
                                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp)
                                {
                                    soundcloudList.get(position).setPlaying(false);
                                    holder.img1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                    holder.img2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                                }
                            });
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

        });
        holder.img2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(final View v)
            {
                Toast.makeText(context,"stop",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();;
                soundcloudList.get(position).setPlaying(false);


                holder.img1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.img2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);


                mMediaPlayer.pause();


            }

        });

        return convertView;

    }

    static class ViewHolder
    {
        public TextView textview;
        public TextView textview2;
        public TextView textview3;
        public ImageView img1;
        public ImageView img2;
        public Button btn;
    }

}
```

SoundCloud

```
public class SoundCloud {
    private String title;
    private String kind;
    private String id;
    private String duration;
    private String download;
    private boolean isPlaying=false;
    public SoundCloud()
    {
        super();


    }
    public String getTitle()
    {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title)
    {
        this.title = title;
    }
    public String getKind()
    {
        return kind;
    }

    public void setKind(String kind)
    {
        this.kind = kind;
    }
    public String getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getDuration()
    {
        return duration;
    }

    public void setDuration(String duration)
    {
        this.duration = duration;
    }

    public String getDownload()
    {
        return download;
    }

    public void setDownload(String download)
    {
        this.download = download;
    }
    public Boolean getPlaying()
    {
        return isPlaying;
    }

    public void setPlaying(Boolean isPlaying)
    {
        this.isPlaying = isPlaying;
    }

}
```

Comment: Just a work around: `if(mMediaPlayer.isPlaying())
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(context,"isplaying",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        mMediaPlayer.pause(); mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                    }`

Comment: Tried moving `setOnPreparedListener` outside onClick then?

Comment: ur first comment helped me to solve the issue partially..if i am playing a track and then try to play another track then the previous track gets stopped and the new track on which i clicked starts playing..Thats fine..But if  i stop the current tack by clicking on stop button and the try to play any track it doesn't get played..

Comment: Answer given by user3249477 is better approach :) try that.

Comment: @MysticMagic That solved my issue..+1 to ur first comment as it also solved one part of my issue.. If i am playing a track and then try to play another track without stopping the previous track then the previous track automatically gets stopped and the new track starts playing..Thats fine..but only issue is that the previous track still shows the pause button icon while it should change to play icon since currently its not playing..glad if u can help me wid tht.,.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you are calling `prepareAsync` multiple times, which should throw an error.

In your onClick listener the first you should call is:

```
mMediaPlayer.reset();
```

Comment: Thanks a lott!! If i am playing a track and then try to play another track without stopping the previous track then the previous track automatically gets stopped and the new track starts playing..Thats fine..but only issue is that the previous track still shows the pause button icon while it should change to play icon since currently its not playing..glad if u can help me wid tht.,.

Comment: @user3753273 you'll need to save the last started song, and in each time onClick listener is called, stop that last song (if one exists).

Comment: should i create a getter setter method in Soundcloud class that contans the postion of last started song and then change the play  stop icon accordingly

Comment: @user3753273 it's up to you **how** you implement it. You can either save the position or the button's view whose drawable you will change.

Comment: @user3753273 You can have a global variable lastPosition in your adapter class, too. which will be set each time in onClick.

Comment: @MysticMagic can u help me with code on that?..thanku for ur time

Comment: @MysticMagic I tried wht u said but still finding problem..check out my issue.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26959345/accessing-image-of-the-last-clicked-item-in-listview