# Accessing image of the last clicked item in listview

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-mediaplayer

Below is the code for the listview adapter which displays list of tracks.Each list item has play and stop icons to play and stop track.When user clicks on play image button it changes to pause button image and track starts playing..When I click on pause button image it changes to play button image and track stops playing.While playing a track if I click on another track play image button previous track stops and the current clicked track start playing but the issue is that previous track still show the pause icon image button while it should change to play image button since currently its not playing.It is because holder.img2 visiblity is still true since we never changed the visiblity of image( holder.img1 is for play icon and holder.img2 is for stop icon).For that i need to access the image icon of the last clicked item in listview..What should i do so that the pause image button should change to play image button if i clicked on another track play button while playing current track..

Comment: You could simplify you life by not repeating the play/pause button for all items but only have it displayed once (on the footer). It would play the selected song.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this:

- Save `position` in a global variable `lastPosition` in `onClick` every time.
- Check if position is not default value, then get its related Row, its images, and set their visibility as per need.

  ```
  int lastPosition = -1;

  holder.img1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
  {
      @Override
      public void onClick(final View v)
      {
          if (lastPosition != -1)  {
              View lastRow = listView.getChildAt(lastPosition);

              ImageView play = (ImageView) lastRow.findViewById(R.id.play2);
              ImageView pause = (ImageView) lastRow.findViewById(R.id.pause);
              play.setVisibility(View.GONE);
              pause.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
          }

      .. //all other code of onClick for media player
      lastPosition = position;
      }
  }
  ```

Hope it helps.

Comment: what should i replace wantedChild with..and in the adapter class i have not declared listview..do i need to declare that?

Comment: lastPosition. Yes. You need to have access to listView.

Comment: I tried that..now if i am playing an audio and then clicked on another track playimage button then app crashed showing null pointer exception on   View lastRow = holder.lv.getChildAt(lastPosition);..check out my updated code in question updated according to ur answer

Comment: statements which i added according to ur answer i have commented out in the above question.

Answer (score 0):

One another way could be by saving last clicked row's `ImageView` directly to `variable` of `SoundCloudAdapter`.

Simple declare a variable global to `SoundCloudAdapter`

```
ImageView imgRowLastClicked;
```

and

```
holder.img1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(final View v)
    {
         if(imgRowLastClicked!= null)       
         {
             lastClickedimg= imgRowLastClicked;
             lastClickedimg.setVisibility(View.GONE);
         }
         //your other code
         imgRowLastClicked= (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.play2);
   }
}
```

Do same for pause `ImageView`

Comment: what should i replace  lastClickedimg with?or wht is lastClickedimg?